# vl53l0x with android things

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

I hope using `VL53L0X` with android Things in raspberry pi 3 b+

```
private static final String I2C_DEVICE_NAME = "I2C1";
private static final int I2C_ADDRESS = 0x52;
    PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();

    List<String> deviceList = manager.getI2cBusList();
    if (deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No I2C bus available on this device.");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "List of available devices: " + deviceList);
    }
    byte b=0;
    //i2c연결
    try {
        mDevice = manager.openI2cDevice(I2C_DEVICE_NAME, I2C_ADDRESS);

        String name= mDevice.getName();
        Log.w(TAG, "connected"+name);
```

This code connect `i2c` connected android things `VL53L0X`

But I can't understand read distance data

Comment: Are you getting any distance data from VL53L0X? Can you post a sample of what you're getting.

Comment: Android Things is not supported on the Raspberry Pi 3B+

Comment: sorry, use raspberry pi 3 B-

Comment: How do you try to read distance data?